# SQL Query: How to check for the Join condition in ON clause only if a condition is true

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to join tables and get the result but I have a condition like, in the ON clause one join condition should be checked only if another condition is true.
For Eg:

```sql
SELECT a.plan_id, a.plan_name, a.sale_s1, b.sale_s1
from (SELECT plan_id, plan_name, sale_s1, sale_s2
     from RESULT_TABLE
      where plan_id = 1245 and sale_id = (any integer value))a
JOIN (SELECT plan_id, plan_name, sale_s1, sale_s2
        from RESULT_TABLE where plan_id = 1245 and sale_id=(any integer value))b
    ON a.plan_id = b.plan_id AND (2nd CONDITION: SHOULD BE CHECKED only if(sale_id=0))
```

All the columns are NOT NULLABLE

Please help me with this, how to achieve the case for that 2nd condition.

Comment: Can sale_id be null?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: sale_id cannot be null @jarlh

Comment: I am using postgres @jarlh

Answer (score 1):

If sale_id is NOT NULL:

```
AND (sale_id <> 0 OR (2nd CONDITION))
```

Comment: Hi @jarlh
I am not able to get the result with this. I am getting the error: "Ambiguous or non-equi join condition specified. Consider using table list with where clause."

Comment: If you show us your actual SQL query, it will be easier to assist you! A [mcve] is the best way to get helped.